# Questions about speaker design?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about **speaker design** allowed?

I have always wanted to post a question asking what the major differences were between a PA speaker, a guitar cab, mixing speakers **coaxial** speakers, etc.

I could see this being a *stretch* as it more relates to equipment and less theory and practice, however, I feel a lot of people would benefit/appreciate this kind of question as we all listen to music through speakers.

Comment: Have a quick look at Sound Design Stack Exchange, although I think this may be marginal there. http://sound.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DrMayhem In my opinion, this should be considered on-topic here. Me personally, I'm for questions about stage equipment and stuff. However, asking about "major differences between" doesn't make a perfect SE question, does it?

Comment: It doesn't look like this question really belongs anywhere. Got shot down real quick: http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/questions-about-speak-design

Comment: I want to understand how these speaker designs affect the sound before they reach our ears. Obviously, each design has a huge effect on our perceivable EQ.

Comment: I have often wondered this myself.  In experimenting with my own equipment once I plugged a bass cab with a 15" speaker rater for 200 Watts into my PA cranking out 600 watts and it emitted sound for about two seconds before the speaker was reduced to tattered shards.  I learned that guitar cabinet speakers are not designed to withstand the high spl levels produced by higher wattage PA systems.  I have also tried lower powered PA amps with high watt rated stereo speakers that sound great with my receiver but distorted through the PA amp.  But I would love to know more about the whys.

Comment: Isn't there an equipment tag?  This would fall under sound reinforcement for musicians and be kind of in the same vein of asking about amplifiers and microphones which I see many questions about.  So I am inclined to want to see it allowed.

Comment: To me your question is not about speaker design (as in how to design speakers), but about equipment differences. It is 100% on topic here.

Comment: piofusco - while there are some ways to word the question that would be on topic here (although more on topic over on sound design!) you may need to work it a bit